# Not able to access ng-model variables when using ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I have the following **Form** which I am including in the main app through **ng-view**

**Form Snippet**

```
<form action = "#" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="commentForm" role="form">      
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10">
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="userComment" placeholder="New Discussion Topic" rows="5"></textarea>             
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="div_submitComment">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">                    
<button class="btn" type="button" id="submitComment" ng-click="vm.addComment()">Submit comment</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Upon clicking the submit button, the controller function will be called. In the controller function, I am not able to access the variable **$scope.userComment**

**Controller Snippet**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DiscussionBoardController', DiscussionBoardController);

DiscussionBoardController.$inject = ['UserService', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$cookieStore', 'AuthenticationService'];
function DiscussionBoardController(UserService, $rootScope, $scope, $cookieStore, AuthenticationService) {  

    function addComment() {                         

        $.getJSON(
        "http://localhost/DBoardPage/server/discussion-board/postComment.php",              // The server URL 
        { userName: $scope.currentUser ,  userComment:$scope.userComment , commentID:0 },   // Data you want to pass to the server.
        $scope.addCommentResponse                                           // The function to call on completion.
        );      
    };
    /*End - Discussion Board related Functions*/
}
```

})();

Though I know that a child scope will be created when we use ng-include, ng-view and ng-repeat, I am not getting an example to explain the usage.

Please let me know how I can get around this preoblem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't $scope.currentUser that doesn't exist?  You are using a variable that isn't declared.

Try adding:

$scope.currentUser = "";
$scope.userComment = "";

Since you are using AngularJS it might be a better idea creating your function the Angular way.

$scope.addComment = function(){....

If it still doesn't work show more of your setup.

Comment: The variable userComment is assigned with ng-model. I expect this to be in scope even without declaring it. When I used ng-controller="DiscussionBoardControlleras vm" and accessed the variables through vm, its working fine now